# JOINs and FOREACH in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I need to know if it's mandatory to use `FOREACH` for any relation transformation in Apache pig. Could you help me understand which one of following approach is better and can help in performance improvement. The file sizes are huge.

**Approach1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input1' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, name:chararray);
B = LOAD 'input2' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, dept:int, dname:chararray);
C = JOIN A by id, B by id;
```

**Approach2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input1' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, name:chararray);
B = LOAD 'input2' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int, dept:int, dname:chararray);
C = FOREACH A GENERATE id, name;
D = FOREACH B GENERATE id, dname;
E = JOIN C by id, D by id;
DUMP E;
```

Comment: If you don't get along with the head of dev ops who manages the hadoop cluster,it doesn't matter whether you use a JOIN or FOREACH.Your job will be relegated to the end of the job queue with the least priority/resources.Approach 1 is the right way and Approach 2 doesn't do anything other than selecting certain columns.See here for more performance tips https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/perf.html

Comment: I would suggest approach #2 where "Project Early and Often" approach is used, Test both the approaches and see how much time it takes, as per docs - https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/perf.html#projection, they have observed time efficiency of 50% with approach #2.